# Possible to know if there is an active search in vim

Tags: vim

I would like to map `<space>` in normal mode to go to the next search result `n`, and `<shift-space>` to go to the previous search-result, `N`, **if there is an active search**. Is it possible to know if there's currently a search that's been applied to the page? For example:

[image]

If so, how could I do such a mapping for this case?

Comment: "[Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/128421)"

Comment: This doesn't make sense. "Searching" is active while you're typing a pattern in the command-line. Otherwise it is in Normal mode and "active search" is only in your mind.

Comment: @Matt yes it would be in normal mode. I guess the definition of 'having an active search' in normal mode would be whether pressing `n/N` would advance to another result. For example in the above image I am in normal mode (as it says), but there are (at least) two entries for `File` highlighted on the active screen -- if I pressed `n` it would go to line 244.

Comment: "Would advance"? And how it's supposed to work? By "try & catch"? Looks totally weird to me.

Answer (score 0):

The `/` register holds the most recently searched pattern. However, the contents of the register are retained between vim sessions, so even if you just opened a file it will probably have something in it. There is no way to tell if you have searched for something in the current file or even in the current session. You might be able to hack together a very bad solution by clearing the register when you open a new file and checking whether it's empty, but that will fail often.